# Is there an equivalent in the World of Darkness to Pathfinder's 'Aid Another' action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

Pathfinder has the [Aid Another](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Aid-Another) action.  It allows non-combat-oriented characters to provide a small bonus to others in their party if they succeed in a very easy attack.

Does the New World of Darkness have anything analogous?  I like that having zero points in Brawl and Weaponry makes me think outside the box, but sometimes I just want to take part in a beatdown!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can remember, there's no exact duplicate of that in Storytelling (but others may correct me.) However, you can achieve something similar, but it's a dangerous thing to try and pull off, as you have to practically engage the opponent, becoming a potential target for them as well. (Right, coming to think of it, the same holds true of Pathfinder as well, where the opponent can also switch to attacking you.)

It all comes down to the workings of the Defense trait. Remember, **each subsequent attack against a character in the same round reduces said character's Defense by one** (nWoD, p90). All you and your co-attacker have to do is **agree on you attacking first, and your co-attacker delaying their attack until you've completed yours. This way your opponent will have a smaller Defense against your co-attacker's attack.**

Sure, **your opponent may decide to use their Defense only against your co-attacker** (nWoD, p156), **but in this case you'd have a much greater chance to score a hit**, since their Defense would not be applied against your weaker attack, as delaying the application of Defense for a specific attack denies all Defense for any attacks coming before the specified attack.

Again, this is dangerous, as you have to practically enter combat, and may become the opponent's primary target - but the same holds true of the Pathfinder option as well, imo.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to cause an effect in combat that's not necessarily an attack, but will give other people fighting on your side an advantage, what you want is a **tilt**. You can find the rules for them in *Danse Macabre* for Vampire: the Requiem and on page 206 of the **God-Machine Chronicle.** (The rules update parts of GMC are available as a free download; they're worth checking out.) It's not as simple as an Aid Another check; the roll you'll have to make will vary based on the Condition you're trying to apply, but it definitely accomplishes the goal of changing the nature of the fight without necessarily being good at the fighting part.

Answer (score 2):

V20 has a possible answer to this problem on page 276:

> **Multiple Opponents:** A character who battles multiple opponents in close combat suffers attack and defense difficulties of +1, cumulative, for each opponent after the first (to a maximum of +4).

So, if you engage the target enemy in combat all at once, you will help all of your friends who are also fighting him by making it *a lot* easier for them to hit him and defend from his blows. If all of you attack him at once, he will face maximum difficulty (10) for all of his combat rolls, making it extremely hard to score any successes.
However, as far as I know it, nWoD uses constant difficulty instead of variable, so it will not be easily transferable over there.

What you can also do is performing other combat maneuvers listed on pages 276-278, some of them do not deal direct damage to the enemy, but rather make it easier for others to attack him. Even though those maneuvers actually need some combat skills to be present, you still have a small chance to perform them successfully in any case, and this chance is probably bigger than successfully dealing damage to a combat character as a non-combat one. Moreover, even trying to perform them counts as being in combat with the enemy, thus applying penalties to the latter.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:
Taking from the real world, and how noncombat caracters deal with combat situation, 
a player of mine got into a combat, without any skills and pulled out a can of mace (pepper spary), and maced the guy so badly he could barely open the door to run away.

Rules for Mace can be found on page 140 of WoD core.
Roughly: Roll Dex+Athletics-1 - defense. On a success the target takes -5 to all actions for rest of the scene.
While the dice pool isn't big, getting one success is all you need.
Vs a combat character needs to get alot of successes to have a impact in a fight.

There are also option for weapons that use Athletics rather than weaponry/firearms/brawl, though that is more a technicality.
Bows and Thrown weapons in particular(see Armoury rules).
I once had a character that could kill a man by throwing bullets at him.